# AVR Excitation System and Generator in SimuLink

Tags: electric-machine, synchronous

I am designing in simulink cooperation of synchronous machines with the grid.
The main blocks are Excitation System which is AVR [[link1]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/excitationsystem.html) and Synchronous Machine [[link2]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/synchronousmachine.html).

On the site we can find

> "Regulator output limits and gain
>   Limits Efmin and Efmax are imposed on the output of the voltage regulator. The upper limit can be constant and equal to Efmax, or variable and equal to the rectified stator terminal voltage Vtf times a proportional gain Kp. If Kp is set to 0, the former applies. If Kp is set to a positive value, the latter applies. Default is [ -11.5, 11.5, 0 ]."

but those coefficents are nowhere properly explained.

I tested it and it limits the output of the regulator to the defualt value which is 11.5 and then the referal value of Vf is straight line (on Efmax level) until the regulator starts to lower down the field current and voltage.

For safe reasons I need to know:

- where this values (Efmin Efmax) comes from in means of finding the formula for them?
- how to set it properly for specific AVR model or Generator?

Schematic of the regulator:
[image]

I also have found that the values of limitations for different models of Excitation Systems varies from ~2-15 (pu)

Comment: what does "AVR" mean here? You're using the [tag:avr] tag, but that means a family of microcontroller cores.

Comment: @MarcusMüller automatic voltage regulator, sorry it may be mistaken I will edit